# How an event horizon forms from a spherically symmetric collapsing shell

Tags: special-relativity, black-holes

I have a question about how an event horizon can form from a spherically symmetric collapsing shell.  Using the following logic, I'm trying to understand what I'm missing here.

Consider a meter stick at rest at the center of a collapsing spherically symmetric collapsing shell in space.  The meter stick inside the shell stretches from the center of the shell out to a distance 2GM (the shell is at a radius greater than 2GM so the entire stick is in flat space).  An observer in freefall on the collapsing shell does so with speed (in natural units measured by her clock):

$$
\frac{dr}{d\tau}=-\sqrt{\frac{2GM}{r}}
$$

Therefore, the freefall observer will see observers at rest at r moving past her at the speed given in the above equation.  Since the meter stick is also at rest relative to observers at rest at any r, the above eqquation will also give the relative velocity between the freefall observer and the meter stick when the shell is at r.  Since the spacetime between the freefall observer and central observer is flat, they will each see the other’s clock dilated by the Special Relativity Relationship:

$$
d\tau=dt\sqrt{1-V^2}=dt\sqrt{1-\frac{2GM}{r}}
$$

Because the meter stick will appear to be moving in the frame of the freefalling observer, its length in her frame would be:

$$
L=2GM\sqrt{1-\frac{2GM}{r}}
$$

We see from the last equation that as the freefalling observer approaches r=2GM the length of the meter stick in her frame will contract to zero length.  So observers in freefall will see the space beyond r=2GM fully contracted as they approach r=2GM.  Furthermore, the clock of an observer at the center of the shell will be slowed as the shell collapses (the clock of an observer at the center ticks at a rate equal to an observer at rest at the location of the shell) such that if she exchanges light signals with the shell as it collapses, the time she measures for the light to return will shrink to zero as the shell reaches the Schwarzschild radius.  Thus, she also effectively sees the space within the shell shrink to zero as the shell approaches the Schwarzschild radius.

So doesn't this mean that for a collapsing shell, in the frame of someone on the shell, the material of the shell will collide when or before the event horizon forms (before the horizon forms, light exchanged between the material in the shell will be very blueshifted creating an increasing pressure as the shell collapses)?  This would scatter the material, preventing the horizon from forming.

In the frame of a distant observer, in the far future, it would appear as if the shell collided with a surface in spacetime, resulting in the same scatter.

I'm wondering what it is I'm misunderstanding with this analysis.